# How to change the terminal title

Tags: zsh, title, oh-my-zsh, hyperterm

I'm currently using Hyper terminal on a mac, but this question also applies to other types of terminals, e.g. iTerm

How do you change the terminal title from `username@devicename:~` into just `~` or `zsh`.

Currently my shell is zsh with oh-my-zsh installed.  I'm not looking for workarounds through powerline or themes.

**One more question:**
How do you reset back after running `echo -n -e "\033]0;SERVER\007"`?

Answer (score 22):

Within `~/.zshrc`

Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.

```
DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"
```

Comment: I had to Restart the terminal after making the change to make this work

Answer (score 11):

I'm using this in my `.zshrc`:

```sh
# oh-my-zsh seems to enable this by default, not desired for 
# workflow of controlling terminal title.
DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

function set_terminal_title() {
  echo -en "\e]2;$@\a"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you googled to search for an answer? How about the following:
https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/mac-os-x/change-title-bar-of-mac-os-x-terminal-window

```
echo -n -e "\033]0;YOUR TITLE HERE\007"
```

Comment: That didn't do what I wanted.  I tried on my mac's built in terminal with `echo -n -e "\033]0;SERVER\007"` and now it looks like `username@devicename -- ~ -- -zsh`.  How do I reset it back?  Also, is there more of a .zshrc type of approach?

Comment: this does not work if remotely connected to a machine

Answer (score 3):

If you can to set terminal name to "Terminal" instead of "username@devicename:~PWD" everytime you open a new zsh terminal you can do this:

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

Uncomment (you can find the line by ctrl+W)

```
DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"
```

Apply changes to your terminal by

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

If you want to set custom names to your terminals you can write this funcation at the end of ~./zshrc file and apply changes using source.

```
function stitle() {
  echo -en "\e]2;$@\a"
}
```

Can be used by:

```
source ~/.zshrc
stitle new title
```

Answer (score 2):

With iterm 2 3.3.3 there's a setting under preferences->profiles->general-basics->title that you can set to PWD (and a few other options). It seems they changed a few things related to this recently and this overrides whatever is in the .zshrc.

I'm guessing one of these options might turn of this behavior as well. In my case PWD is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

case $TERM in xterm*)
    precmd () {print -Pn "\e]0;%~\a"}
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

For Mac, first:

```
brew install wmctrl
```

then for Mac or Linux

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -N "~"
```

in the active window. Type man `wmctrl` if you want to say ways to select a window that is not active.